# How could XGBoost beat perfect logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, simulation, boosting, model-evaluation

I try to compare the logistic regression with XBGoost on the simulated data. What I found is that XBGoost AUC is better than that of logistic regression, **even when logistic regression predict perfect probability (the probability used to generate binary outcome)**.

Please see details below:

1. Simulate X: generate 4 random variables (x1,x2,x3 and x4).See code section A.
2. Similate Y: Let log_odds = x1+x2+x3+x4 (setting all coefficient to 1 and intercept to 0). Then convert log_odds to probability, and use probability to generate binary outcome. See code section B.
3. Fit logistic regression. The estimated coefficients are very close to ones used for similation.**The AUC is 0.834.**
   coef: [[0.92180079 1.07390035 0.97258221 0.80164048]] Intercept [-0.00462648]. See code section C.
4. Fit XGBoost. **The AUC is 0.908**.See code section D.
5. Simulate testing set with different random seed. **Logistic regression AUC is 0.83**6, and **XGBoost AUC is 0.907**. See code section E.

As I understand, when I use simulated probability to generate binary outcomes, I was introducing randomness to the data, which could not be modelled/predicted. However, if the logistic regression already predict probabilities that are so close to the simulated ones,   how could XGBoost generate better performance.

Is this a problem of AUC, my test design, or my code? Thank you very much in advance!

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import rand

# Section A: Simulate X
random.seed(1)
seed(1)
n=10000
x1=np.array(rand(n))*4-2
x2=x1+np.array(rand(n))
x3=-np.array(rand(n))*1.9  
x4=np.array(rand(n))*1
print(sum(x1<=x2)==n)
df=pd.DataFrame({"x1":x1,"x2":x2,"x3":x3,"x4":x4})

# Section B: Simulate Y
def logistic(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
lp=x1+x2+x3+x4
prob = logistic(lp)
y = np.random.binomial(1, prob.flatten())

# Section C: Fit logistic regression and check AUC
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
LR = LogisticRegression()
LR.fit(df.values,y)
print("coef:      ",LR.coef_, LR.intercept_)
print("AUC:       ",LR.score(df, y))

# Section D: Fit XGBoost and check AUC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, plot_tree
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, auc, log_loss

fit_xgb= XGBClassifier(booster='gbtree', numWorkers=1, n_estimators=10, minChildWeight=15.0, seed=1, 
                               objective='binary:logistic', maxDepth=3,eta=0.08, reg_lambda=10.0, alpha=10.0, 
                               gamma=0.0, colsampleBytree=0.7, subsample=0.8)

fit_xgb.fit(df, y)
xgb_prob = fit_xgb.predict_proba(df)[:,1]
print('XGB AUC is', roc_auc_score(y, xgb_prob))

# Section E: Simulate testing set with different random seed, and check AUC
random.seed(10)
seed(10)
n=10000
x1_1=np.array(rand(n))*4-2
x2_1=x1_1+np.array(rand(n))
x3_1=-np.array(rand(n))*1.9   
x4_1=np.array(rand(n))*1
print(sum(x1_1<=x2_1)==n)
df_1=pd.DataFrame({"x1":x1_1,"x2":x2_1,"x3":x3_1,"x4":x4_1})

lp_1=x1_1+x2_1+x3_1+x4_1
prob_1 = logistic(lp_1)
y_1 = np.random.binomial(1, prob_1.flatten())

xgb_prob_1 = fit_xgb.predict_proba(df_1)[:,1]
print('XGB AUC on testing set is:    ', roc_auc_score(y_1, xgb_prob_1)) 
print("Logistic regression AUC is:   ",LR.score(df_1, y_1))
```

Comment: Looks like you're evaluating the model on the same data it was trained.  What happens when you use a hold out set to evaluate ROC?

Comment: @DemetriPananos In step 5 (see code section E), I change the random seed from 1 (for training set) to 10 (for testing set). Thus the testing data is separately generated. The training set AUC are (Logistic: 0.834; XGBoost: 0.908); the testing set AUC are (Logistic: 0.836; XGBoost: 0.907)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is primarily a code issue, the code compares mean accuracy against AUC-ROC. Please see my answer below for more details. In general when comparing probabilistic estimates using [Brier Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score) is preferable but this isn't the main issue here. (+1 though, fun question)

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you very much! Just accepted the answer, and will look in to the Brier Score as well.

Comment: You're not actually fitting a logistic regression. You are fitting a logistic ridge regression. For some reason the default in scikit-learn is to add a ridge penalty, which can help or hurt your ability to perfectly recover a regression relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have upvoted Sycorax's answer as useful. Nevertheless, I think there is a serious issue with the question:  [`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score) returns the *mean accuracy*, not AUC-ROC. If we used  `LR.predict_proba(df_1)[:,1]` to get the predicted probabilistic estimates AUC-ROC values both in the training and testing sets would be higher for the "perfect" logistic regresssion model than XGBoost. For example, in the testing  set, XGBoost's AUC-ROC is: 0.9071 and the AUC-ROC score from the logistic regression is: 0.9167.

Comment: Yep, that would do it.

Comment: Still a useful answer from you though! :) I started looking at this thinking: "The Brier score should pick this up, I will talk about having proper scoring rules, etc." then I was like "Oh... darn."

Comment: Honestly, it's mystifying to me that sklearn implements the `score` method *at all.* It's just another sharp corner that people get cut on all the time. Once the library matured to letting you specify a scoring metric to use for pipelines (like CV), the choices baked into the default `score` became a trap.

Comment: Why would the logistic regression be better in-sample?

Comment: @Dave: Sorry, I might misinterpret your question. I haven't said anything about the in/out-of-sample distinction in my answer, I just mention testing sets for reference. That said, using a testing/out-of-sample set is just trying to avoid evaluating the learners on the same data it was trained. Obviously, given we *know* the DGP and we essentially back-fit against it, we should not expect substantial differences in the metrics between in- and out-of-sample evaluations.